# Hexfloat manipulator and precision

Tags: c++, c++11, hex, precision

How come output using the `hexfloat` manipulator ignores any precision on `ostream`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    cout << setw(17) << left << "default format: " << setw(20) << right << 100 * sqrt(2.0) << " " <<  cout.precision() << '\n'
         << setw(17) << left << "scientific: " << setw(20) << right << scientific << 100 * sqrt(2.0) << " " <<  cout.precision() <<  '\n'
         << setw(17) << left << "fixed decimal: " << fixed << setw(20) << right << 100 * sqrt(2.0) << " " <<  cout.precision() <<  '\n'
         << setw(17) << left << "hexadecimal: " << hexfloat << setw(20) << right << uppercase << 100 * sqrt(2.0) << nouppercase << " " <<  cout.precision() <<  '\n'
         << setw(17) << left << "use defaults: " << defaultfloat << setw(20) << right << 100 * sqrt(2.0) << " " <<  cout.precision() <<  "\n\n";

}
```

Despite a default precision of 6 this seems to get ignored when outputting the double in hexadecimal format ([coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c20c577d15b129cd)) (gcc 5.2.0):

```
default format:               141.421 6
scientific:              1.414214e+02 6
fixed decimal:             141.421356 6
hexadecimal:     0X1.1AD7BC01366B8P+7 6
use defaults:                 141.421 6
```

Is it possible to ensure a decimal precision of 6 using hexadecimal format?

Comment: See [LWG 671](http://wg21.link/lwg671).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `std::hexfloat` format is intended to dump out the exact repesentation of a floating point value. The string represention isn't for human consumption but primarily to restore the exact same representation again. Thus, it does not make sense to truncate the format in any way based on any stream setting.